# Wso2 Private Paas installation is stopped

Tags: amazon-ec2, wso2

I am creating wso2 Paas on Amazon Ec2 by following the instructions in Quick Start Guide with Screencasts. After running the ./boot.sh am getting the following message.

Starting WSO2 Private PaaS server as ubuntu user...

Nothing happens after this message and the terminal is frozen after 2 hours.

I am using centos 6.7, screen terminal and amazon ec2 instance type is t1.micro, ami is Private PaaS    ami-4e062c1c  for doing this.

Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 has discontinued WSO2 Private PaaS solution. Please refer [1] for the new PaaS strategy. On AWS, WSO2 middleware can be deployed either on VMs using AWS deployment automation and autoscaling features or with containers using Kubernetes, DC/OS, ECS.

[1] http://wso2.com/cloud/paas/